# Access denied for user ''@'10.246.64.24' (using password: NO)

Tags: php, sql, database

I'm trying to write a registration form, firstly I tried to do it OO, but this didn't respond, it seemed to just clear the form and refresh the page, but didn't insert any data:

EDIT: Current code:

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'registrationform.php';
include 'connection.php';

if (isset($_POST['regsubmit'])) 
    {
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$user = $_POST['username'];    
$pass = $_POST['password'];
$query = "INSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname, username, password) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)";
$statement = $connection->prepare($query);
//bind parameters for markers, where (s = string, i = integer, d = double,  b = blob)
$statement->bind_param('ssss', $firstname, $lastname, $username, $password);

if($statement->execute()){
     print 'Success! ID of last inserted record is : ' .$statement->insert_id .'<br />'; 
     //$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
}else{
     die('Error : ('. $mysqli->errno .') '. $mysqli->error);
}
$statement->close();
?>
```

**Registration Form**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
include 'header.php';
?>
<center>

<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="web.css" />


</font>
    <head>


    </head>
    <body> 

    <div id="registrationform">

        Please enter your registration details<br /><br />

        <form method="post" action="registrationsubmit.php">
            First Name:
            <input type="text" name="firstname" />
            <br /><br>
            Last Name:
            <input type="text" name="lastname" />
            <br /><br>
            Username:
            <input type="text" name="username" />
            <br /><br>
            Password:
            <input type="text" name="password" />
            <br /><br>
            <input type="submit" name="regsubmit" value="Submit" />
        </form>

</div>



        </body>
</html>

</center>
```

**OO Attempt**

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'registrationform.php';
include 'connection.php';

if (isset($_POST['regsubmit'])) 
    {
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$user = $_POST['username'];    
$pass = $_POST['password'];
$stmt = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO users VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param('ssss', $firstname, $lastname, $user, $pass);
$stmt->execute();
printf("%d Row inserted.\n", $stmt->affected_rows);  
$stmt->close();
}
?>
```

As this wasn't working I tried just doing it without OO, for a starting point. But now I'm given the error "Access denied for user ''@'10.246.64.24' (using password: NO)", yet my connection connects fine and I've also written a login that works perfectly so can't figure it out. Here is the current code that I have:

**registrationsubmit.php**

```
<?php
include "connection.php";
include "header.php";
if(isset($_POST['regsubmit']))
{
 mysql_select_db("c3438525_co_uk",$connection);
 $firstname = $_POST['$firstname'];
 $lastname = $_POST['$lastname'];
 $username = $_POST['username']; 
 $password = $_POST['password'];
 $query = "INSERT INTO users (FirstName, LastName, Username, Password) VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$username', '$password')"; 
 $data = mysql_query ($query)or die(mysql_error()); 
 if($data) { echo "Successfully Registered"; }

 else
 {
  ?>
        <script>alert('error while registering you...');</script>
        <?php
 }
}
?>
```

**Connection.php**

```
 <?php
ob_start();
$connection = mysqli_connect("***", "***", "BFUWGpn3", "***"); 
?>
```

Comment: @MarcB how is this a duplicate of [Can I mix MySQL API's in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17498216/can-i-mix-mysql-apis-in-php)?

Comment: @SmallLegend: connection.php: `mysqli_connect()`. registration_submit.php: `mysql_query()`. mysql_*() will attempt to auto-connect with default username/pw upon first usage, and is obviously failing.

Comment: @MarcB Yeah I understand that, but that isn't his question

Comment: yes, and? exactly how can it insert anything if OP's using the **WRONG** mysql function for the insert query? `mysql_query('INSERT ...')` is faling because OP used `mysqli` to connect in the first place.

Comment: @MarcB so surely it shouldn't be marked as a duplicate, but you should refer him to this question? I'm not looking to argue, I'm still learning the ropes with SO

Comment: OP's problem is entirely due to mixing the libraries, so the question is a dupe.

Comment: Thankyou @MarcB - so should I change my connection.php to connect through mysql instead of mysqli?

Comment: @user2326995 no, use mysqli_, mysql_ is deprecated

Comment: mysql is dead in the water, and will be removed from a future version of php. Use PDO or MySQLi only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a mysqli_ connection and your query is mysql_

For the `registrationsubmit.php`

Use something on the lines:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname, username, password) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)";
$statement = $connection->prepare($query);
//bind parameters for markers, where (s = string, i = integer, d = double,  b = blob)
$statement->bind_param('ssss', $firstname, $lastname, $username, $password);

if($statement->execute()){
     print 'Success! ID of last inserted record is : ' .$statement->insert_id .'<br />'; 
     //$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
}else{
     die('Error : ('. $mysqli->errno .') '. $mysqli->error);
}
$statement->close();
```

Refer to : http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

Comment: Cheers mate, gave this a go but now it just returns a white screen

Comment: I edited it, try it again and check the error message

Comment: Still white screening I'm afraid. I'll edit my code to what I have now.

Comment: I am on PHP 5.6, does this change anything?

Comment: In your current code, I believe your missing a } before the ?>

Comment: missing } before the else actually

Comment: @RalphMelhem I must be missing something?

Comment: @SmallLegend never mind mate, got mixed up between the inner If statement and the outer one

Comment: @SmallLegend - Added this in, it seems to have fixed the white screen error but it now displays Error() but without the error number.

Ralph - There is a } before the else if I'm not mistaken?

Comment: I've just logged into my PHP, I've noticed that my php link is: https://dbadmin.one.com/index.php, however I am not using index.php for my homepage anymore. Maybe this is an issue?

Comment: I can imagine this could be an issue, the above query should work, entrusting that the post variables and connection are stable

Comment: Yeah can't see why it wont, but it just keeps displaying the error message without showing any of the error numbers

Comment: @user2326995 whats the error message?

Comment: It's calling this line: die('Error : ('. $mysqli->errno .') '. $mysqli->error);

but no errno

Comment: Is the connection working? echo out the posted variables, do they work?

Comment: Success! got it to work. Thanks mate. I will update my code :)

Comment: @user2326995 well done mate :)